# Visual Studio 2017 blank project open dialog and hang

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I installed 2017 and used it for some time (months). After one of the updates, I started having trouble in the file browser window not navigating to other folders without hanging.  I can't navigate or choose a file. the app is hung here. I have left it up for several minutes and it stays hung there. I have to kill it from Task Manager in the current version; in prior versions it hung the system and I had to power off. I saw similar problems posted and a reply that indicated it was reproduced and would be fixed. I starting using VS 2015 again in the meantime. That was a few release ago. I had hopes that the most recent one (now on 15.7.3) might fix it since it was fairly large. It made me have a different issue in the same dialog. Now it is blanked out and only VS 2017 is hung. That's a little better since I don't have to restart my system every time I try to run it. But I really need to move to VS 2017.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. I have uninstalled and re-installed several times and tried uninstalling and reinstalling the more recent .net versions.

Windows 10 Enterprise, kept current with Windows Update, 32G RAM

[On trying to browse for a solution, this comes up.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0Cw1.jpg)

Comment: Any extra plugings installed like Resharper? Tried deleting "%AppData%\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio"?

Comment: Does it hang after you've selected the project or just simply opening the open dialog?

Comment: @Liam - simply opening. After removing the folder, i uninstalled and also removed one in Local the reinstalled and rebooted. Now it doesn't come up blank but as soon as I try to navigate to another folder it hangs. I have VS 2015; works fine. I have dozens of working applications in the machine. VS 2017 is the only thing that displays this behavior. No extra plugins - fresh install. Chose C# editor settings, did not import from previous.